# How to provide capability like OnActivate (in Autofac) in Mvx.IoCProvider.Register

Tags: reflection, inversion-of-control, autofac, mvvmcross, ioc-container

**Autofac** provides the `OnActivated()` method, which provides the capability to run any action after constructing a registered type.

Is possible to use a similar method in **MvvmCross**? Do you have any ideas to provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It usually pays to understand the fundamentals of Dependency Injection (DI) instead of relying on particular DI Container features. Ask yourself the question: *If I didn't have a DI Container, then how would I solve my problem?*

Ironically, it turns out that things are usually much simpler with [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di).

If you didn't have a DI Container, then how would you run an action after construction of an object?

The easiest solution is to provide a factory that creates and initialises the object. Assuming the same API and requirements as [the Autofac documentation implies](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html), you could do this:

```
public static Dependency2 CreateDependency2(ITestOutputHelper output, Dependency1 dependency)
{
    var d2 = new Dependency2(ITestOutputHelper output, Dependency1 dependency);
    d2.Initialize();
    return d2;
}
```

If you still must use another DI Container, most of them enable you to register a factory like the above against the type. I don't know how MvvmCross works, but I'd be surprised if this wasn't possible. If it isn't, you can implement an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) over your actual dependency. The Adapter would take care of running the action on the adapted object.

FWIW, if an object isn't in a valid state before you've run some action on it, then encapsulation is broken. The fundamental characteristic of encapsulation is that objects protect their invariants so that they can never be in invalid states. If possible, consider a better API design.